# Новый контекст БД внутри BackgroundService

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Всем привет!

Фоном прослушивается Discord, оттуда последовательно приходят картинки.

А в MSSQL уже есть данные кому отдавать картинки с ID скажем.

**DiscordMessageService** не должен создаваться при каждом запросе, в этом нет никакой нужды, к нему не обращаются одновременно из разных потоков. И инициализация у него очень долгая. А на другой стороне чат-бот, так что это не вариант.
**MyDbContext** - обязан быть Scoped, тк в основном потоке обращения к БД идут с разных потоков и возможно одновременно.

Но нужно в самом сервисе который слушает, менять данные в БД, но невозможно использовать scoped внутри singlton. Наверняка есть очевидный выход, но я не знаю какой.

```
public class DiscordMessageService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _discordClient;
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public DiscordMessageService( DiscordSocketClient discordClient, MyDbContext _dbContext)

    { 
        _discordClient = discordClient;
        _discordClient.MessageReceived += Client_MessageReceived1;
    }
        
    private async Task Client_MessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
    {
       var data = await _dbContext.Entity.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Prompt == prompt); // -- Хочу немного данных получить ))
       return;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
       await Task.Delay(-1, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

В Startup.cs

```
services.AddHostedService<DiscordMessageService>();
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")),ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

****Как мне получать данные из БД** в моем обработчике тогда?** Спасибо.

Comment: `public DiscordMessageService(DiscordSocketClient discordClient, MyDbContext dbContext)`, не?

Comment: не, я исправил свой вопрос, вероятно он был плохо сформулирован

Comment: [Use scoped services within a BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov
Да, это верное решение. Спасибо. 

Для потомков: Нужно создать фабрику, которая будет создавать новый экземпляр контекста для каждого вызова, возвращает она _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>(); ее зарегистрировать как Singlton . И в BackgroundService уже через нее создавать контекст.

MDSN по сути предлагает тоже самое с использованием IServiceScopeFactory